# Symfony - redirect user to country route by IP

Tags: symfony, translation

In site I have a lot of public pages. Site has several languages.
Pages url like this:
/about-us (english)
/de/about-us (germany)
....

But when user come to the site (from Germany for example), and enter in browser address homepage or /about-us if he first time on my site, I need show /de/about-us.

How can I to do this.

I have Subscriber with

```
 public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
                ['setTranslationsLocale', self::TRANSLATIONS_PRIORITY],
            ],
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'setCountrySpecificLocale',
        ];
    }

public function setTranslationsLocale(RequestEvent $event): void
{
   ...
   $request->setLocale($routeLocale);
   $session->set('_locale', $routeLocale);
   // and locale set correctly
}
```

but because address /about-us (not /de/about-us) language is english. How can i redirect to /de/about-us url (urls can be different)

Comment: You can have a logic to find the right user's locale in the Kernel (before your controllers). See [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration is correct, you can configure all @Route annotation on your controllers like that:

```
 * @Route(
 *  path={
 *      "fr_FR": "/locations",
 *      "en_US": "/rentals",
 *  },
 *  ......
 * )
```

Depending to wich locale is set on the request, the corresponding uri is given to the response.

More informations here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n